# Edit classic app

Tags: paypal

I need to change some payments details in my paypal classic application. Is there anyway to go about this? I need to enable it to be able to send personal payments, I am getting the error:

```
The caller's credential doesn't have permission for the payment type PERSONAL
```

I have emailed the api support email several times over the past 3 months with no response. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Any idea why the send payments was working in sandbox mode but not live on the same app?

Comment: I'm not sure who you emailed, but can you file a ticket with us via https://www.paypal.com/mts please? Include the appID in the ticket and let me know the ticket number here please. I'll route it to the right folks. Thanks!

Comment: @PayPal_Robert that is exactly who I have emailed before. I have submitted another ticket `#131017-000225` thanks for your help!

Comment: I've routed this to the right team. You're saying you have another ticket open with us? Got the ticket#?